# Is it possible to push long words to new line yet keeping the current line as justified text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, line-breaking, paragraphs, line-spacing

I want a document with justified text. However, there are some long words which are coming at the end of lines and are being pushed to the new lines and are being hyphenated.

If I have spacing explicitly, the current line's text does not remain justified.

How to solve for this?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: \sloppy usually can avoid hyphenation.  Not always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\linebreak` to force a line break at that point (unlike `\\` or `\newline` this does not force the line to be short). Normally the spacing will be sub-optimal, but for final manual correction it can be useful.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I think he needs to play with the hyphenation penalty.

Comment: @Diaa I can only answer the question as asked. As I tried to indicate this is not usually the best thing to do but it is the exact answer to the question and I can't guess unseen use cases here.